# Select top most parent from self foreign key related SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, rdbms

I have following SQL table

Area

```
id     name         parent_id
1      Pune         null
2      Mumbai       null
3      area1        1
4      area2        3
```

Here I have logical foreign key `parent_id` so that `area2` has the parent `area1` and `area1` has parent `Pune`. Here  I want to select topmost parent of any subarea.
For ex. when i search `area2` then it will give result `Pune`.

Comment: What query you tried and what error you got?

Answer (score 0):

mysql does not support hierarchical joins (e.g. `WITH RECURSIVE`)

You can either try this solution:

[Hierarchical queries in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/mysql-hierarchical-queries)

Or manipulate the recursion within `php` or any other server-side language you are using

Since you asked in the comments regarding Oracle / MSSQL: [Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1113877),[MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676944/finding-a-top-level-parent-in-sql)

Comment: I've added links for mssql & oracle,

Comment: If this answer was helpful please accept it as answer or at least vote up, thank you.

Comment: How should I do this using postgresql?